# data report text box bold at runtime v.b 6.0

Tags: vb6

My Question is

i am using a table "marks" which have fields like roll_no,name,marks and i wanted to create report which should show name list in bold letters who ever scored more that 80 and underline whoever scored below 40 and all others in regular font.

problem is how to make data report text box bold or underline or regular for certain records based on the marks and where to give coding for the condition criteria.

Kindly answer

Thanks

With Regards.
K.Giridhar Rao"

Comment: I don't believe that sort of conditional formatting is supported.

Answer (score -1):

To make different graphics styles into the same data report line my solution is:
1) define any graphic element into the line
2) map any element as a field of record of data report associated recordset
3) by your code, create a record for each row of report, assign a value for each field to be rendered

Comment: Thanks for answering a question on StackOverflow! Rather than leaving your email address, make sure that answers include examples. That way not only does the person who asked the original question not have to email you and wait for a response, but anyone else who finds this answer later will also be able to get the help they need.